# OpenGL graphics editor...implementation of eraser tool

Tags: opengl, graphics, editor

i'm writing a menu-based OpenGL graphics editor.It is pretty basic. Every time i choose a new option in the pop-down menu, the older drawing disappears,this doesn't allow me to use the eraser tool...could anybody tell me how to solve this problem?thanx

Comment: What platform, libraries are you using? Does the whole drawing disappear, or just the part under the popup? Maybe you're not redrawing/updating the viewport properly.

Comment: i'm using the GLUT libraries.Suppose i choose 'line' option and draw some line,then I click the right button to see the menu and choose another option,the lines that r drawn previously disappear.I think i have to disable the glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) function after menu selection but i dont know how i shud do it.I tried using a flag in the display func like this
display()
{
if(flag==0)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
flag=1;
}
glFlush();
} 
this leads to the pop-up menu staying on the screen.If i select line,the menu stays on screen till i select two points on the screen.
Please help me

Comment: oh come on can NOBODY solve my problem?please?

Comment: Do you hold all the drawn primitives in some array and draw all of them repeatedly? It seems like you only draw the last option from the menu. Just removing `glClear` won't help. You have to repaint the whole canvas at least each time the user performs an action. Can you show the drawing code? Or the main loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague. Anyway...

Are you drawing picture directly on the screen/window? Then of COURSE drawings will disappear.

Paint picture to texture (framebufferObjects or whatever. See NVidia OpenGL SDK for examples). Then render texture on the screen. clear screen, draw texture, then draw menu, every time you need to repaint window.